# Why SSIS Package Succeeds but Flat File Destinations Write Zero Rows?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a very straightforward, in my opinion, SSIS package comprised of 8 Data Flow Tasks.  Each task is composed of an OLEDB Source that calls a query stored in a variable and a Flat File Destination that writes the contents of the query to a pipe-delimited text file on the network.

The original version of the package worked but the package needed modification to add new fields to the flat files.  I deleted all Flat File Destinations and corresponding connection managers and created new ones.  The queries have been tested independently and they return data.  The OLEDB SQL Server provider uses Windows Authentication.

The package is executed inside Visual Studio 2019 and runs successfully, but each of the 8 resulting flat files are empty except for the column headers.

[image: This is a sample data flow task's OLEDB Source]

I've updated my Visual Studio 2019 installation to use the Integration Services extension 4.3 (latest).  I copied the following query from one of my variables to SSMS and receive results:

```
Declare @PrevYearSvcStartDate date = '1/1/2021', @PrevYearSvcEndDate 
date = '12/31/2021',
@PrevYearPaidStartDate date = '1/1/2021', @PrevYearPaidEndDate date = 
'12/31/2021'

SELECT Distinct
mmpi.FIRSTNM AS 'Claimant First Name',--       Claimant First Name
mmpi.LASTNM AS 'Claimant Last Name',-- Claimant Last Name
ISNULL(mmpi.MI, '') AS 'Claimant Middle Initial',--     Claimant Middle Initial
mc.MEMBID AS 'Claimant Identification Number',-- Claimant Identification Number (to include the member number & suffix if applicable)
Format(mmpi.BIRTH, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'Claimant Date of Birth ', -- Claimant Date of Birth 
Format(mhp.OPFROMDT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'Claimant Effective Date of coverage',--      Claimant Effective Date of coverage
CASE 
when cm.HPCode = 'BB' then 'Bueno Beverage'
when cm.HPCode = 'BC' then 'Blue Cross'
when cm.HPCode = 'BS' then 'Blue Shield'
when cm.HPCode = 'HN' then 'Health Net'
when cm.HPCode = 'HU' then 'Humana'
when cm.HPCode = 'KD' then 'Kaweah Health'
when cm.HPCode = 'RN' then 'R&N Market'
when cm.HPCode = 'UH' then 'United Healthcare'
end AS 'Health Plan name', -- Health Plan name
'Medical Group' AS 'IPA Affiliation', -- IPA Affiliation (e.g. Regal, Lakeside, etc)
 cm.OPT as 'Benefit Option Code',   CASE 
    WHEN cm.HPCODE IN ('BC', 'BS', 'HN', 'UH') 
        THEN 'COMMERCIAL' 
    ELSE 'MEDICARE' 
END AS 'Line of Business', -- Line of Business (e.g. Commercial, 
Medicare, Medicaid)
cm.CLAIMNO AS 'Claim number', -- Claim number
cd.[SEQUENCE] AS 'Claim Sequence Number', -- Claim Sequence Number
COALESCE(NULLIF(pmpi.FIRSTNAME,''),'')
+COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(pmpi.LASTNAME,''),'') AS 'Provider Name',
IsNull(PC.PROVID, '') AS 'Provider ID Number',
IsNull(PA.ZIP, '') AS 'Provider Zip',
IsNull(cc3.Code, '') AS 'Provider Specialty Code',
IsNull(pmpi.SUFFIX, '') AS 'Provider Degree',
ISNULL(cc1.Code, '')  AS 'Place of Service ', -- Place of Service 
Format(cd.FROMDATESVC, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'Date of Service, from date', -- 
Date of Service, from date
Format(cd.TODATESVC, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'Date of Service, through date', - 
- Date of Service, through date
cd.QTY AS 'Procedure quantity', -- Procedure quantity (units)
DATEDIFF(DAY, cd.FROMDATESVC, cd.TODATESVC) AS 'Length of Stay', -- 
Length of Stay (days)
LTrim(Rtrim(ISNULL(cd.HSERVICECD,''))) AS 'Revenue Codes', -- Type of 
Service (UB-92 Revenue Codes)
LTrim(RTrim(ISNULL(cd.PROCCODE, ''))) AS 'Procedure Codes', -- Type of 
Service (CPT Procedure Codes, HCPCS codes, when applicable)
ISNULL(cd.PROCDESC, '') AS 'Type of Service Description', -- Type of 
Service Description
ISNULL(cd.Modif, '') as 'Modifier',
ISNULL(cm.DRGCode, '') AS 'DRG Code', -- DRG Code
CD.DIAGCODE AS 'Diagnosis codes', -- Diagnosis codes
D.DIAGDESC AS 'Diagnosis codes description', -- Diagnosis codes 
description
cd.BILLED AS 'Billed/charged amount', -- Billed/charged amount
cd.CONTRVAL AS 'Contracted amount', -- Contracted amount
cd.ALLOWED AS 'Allowed Amount', --allowed Amount
cd.NET AS 'Paid amount', -- Paid amount
Format(cd.DATEPAID, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'Date paid', -- Date paid
ISNULL(cd.CHECKNO, '') AS 'Check Number',-- Check Number
cm.NET AS 'Covered expense amount basis', -- Covered expense amount 
basis* (e.g. DRG, outliers, per diem, global rate, fee for service 
discount)
CASE 
    WHEN BPHP.LOB_NETWORK = 1 
        THEN 'IN'
    When BPHP.LOB_NETWORK = 0
        Then 'OUT'
    ELSE '' 
END AS 'In/Out of network indicator',-- In/Out of network indicator
ISNULL(cd.ADJCODE,'') AS 'Claim Line Adjustment code', -- Claim Line 
Adjustment code
ISNULL(replace(Replace(cc.[Description],char(10),''),Char(13),''),'') AS 
'Claim Line Adjustment reason', -- Claim Line Adjustment reason
CASE 
         when BPHP.LOB_NETWORK = 1 then 'CP'
when BPHP.LOB_NETWORK = 0 then 'NCP' ELSE ''
END AS 'Contracted/Non-contracted provider indicator', -- 
Contracted/Non-contracted provider indicator
cd.Net
FROM
CLAIM_DETAILS cd
INNER JOIN(
Select ClaimNo, Memb_KeyID, Company_ID, HPCode, OPT, PlaceSvc, Status, 
Net, Vendor, Prov_KEYID, DRGCode
from Claim_HMasters
Union
Select ClaimNo, Memb_KeyID,Company_ID, HPCode, OPT, PlaceSvc, Status, 
Net, Vendor, Prov_KEYID, '' as DRGCode
from Claim_PMasters
) cm ON cd.CLAIMNO = cm.CLAIMNO and cd.Company_ID = cm.Company_ID
inner join Common_Codes cc1 on cm.PlaceSvc = cc1.Common_Code_ID 
and cm.Company_ID = cc1.Environment_ID
and cc1.Common_Category_ID = 59
INNER JOIN MEMB_COMPANY mc on mc.MEMB_KEYID = cm.MEMB_KEYID 
and mc.HPCODE = cm.HPCODE 
and mc.COMPANY_ID = cm.Company_ID
INNER JOIN MEMB_MPI mmpi on mmpi.MEMB_MPI_NO = mc.MEMB_MPI_NO
and mc.Company_ID = mmpi.Environment_ID
LEFT JOIN MEMB_HPHISTS mhp ON mc.MEMB_KEYID = mhp.MEMB_KEYID 
and cd.Company_ID = mhp.Company_ID
and cd.FROMDATESVC BETWEEN OPFROMDT and ISNULL(OPTHRUDT,getdate())
INNER JOIN  (
Select dx.ClaimNo, dx.Company_ID, cdc.Description as DiagDesc
    from Claim_Diags dx
    inner join Claim_Details det on dx.ClaimNo = det.ClaimNo and 
dx.Company_ID = det.Company_ID
    inner join Common_Diagnostic_Codes cdc on dx.DIAG = 
cdc.Common_Diagnostic_Code_ID 
    and dx.Company_ID = cdc.Environment_ID
    where DiagRefNo = '1' 
    and cdc.Environment_ID = 'MSO'
    and det.ToDateSvc between  @PrevYearSvcStartDate and 
@PrevYearSvcEndDate 
    and det.DatePaid between @PrevYearPaidStartDate and  
@PrevYearPaidEndDate 
) D on CD.CLAIMNO = D.CLAIMNO and cd.Company_ID = d.Company_ID
LEFT JOIN  [BM_PROV_HP_LINEOFBUSS] BPHP ON BPHP.PROV_KEYID = 
cm.PROV_KEYID
and BPHP.HPCODE = CM.HPCODE  
AND IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(cm.OPT)) IN    
 ('651244499','651244400','592314503','592314502','592314511',   '592314512','592314514','592314501','592314508','592314507','592314506','592314509','592314599','592314599','625221160','625221164','625221165'), 
'PPO','HMO') = 
BPHP.LOB 
AND BPHP.VENDOR = CM.VENDOR
and BPHP.Company_ID = cm.Company_ID
INNER JOIN PROV_COMPANY pc on pc.PROV_KEYID = cm.PROV_KEYID 
and cm.Company_ID = pc.Company_ID
INNER JOIN PROV_MPI pmpi on pmpi.PROV_MPI_NO = pc.PROV_MPI_NO
and pc.Company_ID = pmpi.Environment_ID
LEFT JOIN PROV_ADDINFO pa ON cm.PROV_KEYID = pa.PROV_KEYID 
and cm.Company_ID = pa.Company_ID
and pa.IsDefault=1
left JOIN Common_Codes cc ON CD.ADJCODE_ID = CC.Common_Code_ID  
and cd.Company_ID = cc.Environment_ID
AND CC.Common_Category_ID = 57 
Inner Join PROV_SPECINFO PS on cm.PROV_KEYID = PS.PROV_KEYID
and cm.Company_ID = ps.Company_ID
And PS.[SEQUENCE] = '1'
left join Common_Codes cc3 on ps.SPec_Code = cc3.Common_Code_ID
and ps.Company_ID = cc3.Environment_ID
 and cc3.Common_Category_ID = 85

WHERE
cm.HPCODE IN ('BS', 'BC', 'HN', 'UH')
    and CD.ToDateSvc between   @PrevYearSvcStartDate and @PrevYearSvcEndDate
and CD.DatePaid between @PrevYearPaidStartDate and @PrevYearPaidEndDate
AND cm.STATUS = '47'
AND substring(cm.ClaimNo,9,1) = '8'
```

What should I check to ensure the package produces data?

Comment: The VS2019 **Data Flow** Task (DFT) shows number of processed rows flowing between Source and Destination. What do you see there?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Usually there is a number but not in the case of this particular SSIS package.

Comment: So you need to copy a Source Adapter query from SSIS to SSMS, run it there, and see if it brings any rows. It is very possible that the `WHERE` clause is filtering all data out.

Comment: Does the query return the expected data if you copy-paste it into an SSMS query tab and execute it? If it were me I'd start by cleaning up the query to remove all of the extraneous `--* ...` code and use properly quoted output column names instead of string literals, e.g.: `[Claimant.FirstName]` instead of `'Claimant.FirstName'`.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I copied the query to SSMS, removed the quotations marks, set by variables and results are returned.

Comment: It is a mistake *"I've updated my Visual Studio 2019 installation to use the Integration Services extension 4.3 (latest)"*. All 4.* versions are experimental, buggy, and missing some functionality. It is better to revert back to the **GA version 3.16**

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks for the suggestion.  I removed the more recent version of the extension and re-installed 3.16.  However, the issue still persists.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  I took your advice and changed one of the 8 scripts to properly quoted output column names.  I also changed the OLEDB Source to a SQL Query, pasted the revised script, and I now have data!!